# Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?' to expected argument type '[AnyObject]!

Tags: json, swift, types, casting, anyobject

I'm using the swift lib ["Sync" from Hyperoslo](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync) to convert a JSON user to a Core Data object.

```
let user = JSON.valueForKey("user")
Sync.changes(user , inEntityNamed: "User", dataStack: DataManager.manager, completion: { (response ) -> Void in
    print("USER \(response)")
})
```

but when a set the first parameter of this method with my JSON object, I have the pre-compiler error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?' to expected argument type
>   '[AnyObject]!'

If a replace my first line by...

```
let user = JSON.valueForKey("user") as! [AnyObject]
```

...the app crash with this error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x3884d7c8) to
>   'NSArray' (0x3884d548).

How to deal with this?

**SOLVED** thanks to the explanations from @Eric.D

```
let user = [JSON.valueForKey("user")!]
```

Comment: user is a Dictionary not an Array so if you force cast it to something it isn't then it will bomb. Do if let user = JSON.valueForKey("user") as? Dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter for `changes()` should be an *implicitly unwrapped array of AnyObject* as specified here:

> https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync#swift

but your object `user` is an optional AnyObject.

Solution: safely unwrap `user` then put it inside a `[AnyObject]` array before using it in `changes()`.

Answer (score 1):

To start, user is an optional AnyObject. You can *never* expect that you can use an optional where anything non optional is required. Typically you will use "if let" to check whether the optional is there.

But really, do you want to put an AnyObject in your database? This is asking for trouble. Check first that it has the right type.